# Sysem wide GUI search

Tags: mate, search

Coming from a Mac, and have experience with Linux (Debian and RHEL) server side, but new to using it as a Desktop OS. In macOS, I can hit command-spacebar to launch applications through Spotlight. I noticed OpenSUSE Leap also has this when hitting the command key (or PC equivalent). Wondering if there is a similar function in Ubuntu. I am running the latest Ubuntu MATE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add mate menu in panel instead of app-places-system menu. Then you can press Windows key to launch the menu and search application from there.